# How to implement unit test program using golang?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

I saw many blogs where they write how to do unit testing but I will understand theory portion and not understand how to implement the test case can anyone will tell me that how will I implement the first test case for more understanding with the unit testing. Here I'm implementing the small program for average:-

**Folder structure is:-**

```
main.go
average(Folder)----> math_test.go
```

code in the both file is:-

**main.go**

```
 package main

 import "fmt"
 import "testcases/average"

 func main() {
    xs := []float64{1,2,3,4}
    avg := m.Average(xs)
    fmt.Println(avg) 
 }
```

**math_test.go**

```
package math

import "testing"

func TestAverage(t *testing.T) {
  var v float64
  v = Average([]float64{1,2})
  if v != 1.5 {
    t.Error("Expected 1.5, got ", v)
  }
 }
```

> ERROR:-  go build testcases/average: no non-test Go files in /home/iron/go/src/testcases/average

Helping me I'm very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the package name with the `main` or `math` as @mkopriva and @whitespace said and place them into the same folder see in example

main.go

```
package main


func Sum(x int, y int) int {
  return x + y
}

func main() {
  Sum(5, 5)
}
```

math_test.go

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestSum(t *testing.T) {
   total := Sum(5, 5)
   if total != 10 {
      t.Errorf("Sum was incorrect, got: %d, want: %d.", total, 10)
   }
}
```

Output:-

> PASS
>   ok     testcases   0.001s

And also a basic example of the testing.

Comment: yeah it works but can provide me a example of doing average

Answer (score 0):

this is because your test file is in `package main`. You can either change your main.go to have `package math`, or change your `math_test.go` to `package main`. Check my git repo, [here](https://github.com/kurianCoding/g4g) I have not written any main function. Yet functions are written, and their output is checked with `testing` package.

Comment: now error coming is `import "testcases/average" is a program, not an importable package`

Comment: @whitespace that's not true, their test file is in package math which lives in folder average, that folder has no non-test files, ie. only one test file, and that's their problem.

Comment: @mkopriva can you ll me how I will do this

Comment: @puneet55667788 first, you should name your package the same as the folder in which they live, this is a convention in Go, that means that either rename the folder average to math or rename the package math to average. Then the package in which you have your test files (*_test.go) also need non-test files that contain the code you want to test. E.g. if math_test.go has a test `func TestAverage` that tests a function called Average then you should have, in the same package a file without _test.go, e.g. math.go, that defines the function Average.

Comment: you mean to say combine all the code into `main.go` @mkopriva

Comment: @mkopriva  can you please provide me an example

Comment: @whitespace I'm checking your repository I found `https://github.com/kurianCoding/g4g/blob/master/g4g_test.go` this link and past in a file and run that file it will give me error of `undefined: HCF
FAIL testcases/math [build failed]`